# How to force EF generate a single MigrationHistory table while using multiple contexts

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework-6

**TLDR:**

I have two EF contexts "locker" and "report". I want to see a single __MigrationHistory table. I want to make the "report" context use the migration history table that "locker" context is using, while keeping the rest of "report" context data on "report" database schema.

**The backstory**

Our project started out having a single EF context "locker". We have our own IDatabaseInitializer class implementation that behaves similarly to`System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`:

```
    public class CheckAndMigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration>
    : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
{
    public virtual void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        var migratorBase = ((MigratorBase)new DbMigrator(Activator.CreateInstance<TMigrationsConfiguration>()));
        if (migratorBase.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
            migratorBase.Update();
    }
}
```

Migrations configuration class implemented `DbMigrationsConfiguration<LockerContext>`
Other than that everything seems to be just the standard out of the box stuff.
This way the tables were generated in the data base under the "dbo" schema.

Then one day the another context was added - "report". And at first the migrations configuration class implemented `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ReportContext>` . We were developing with that for a while. And the relevant report tables were created under report schema, but only a single dbo.__MigrationHistory table was being generated and report context was also using.

Unfortunately for us we released this into production. We did not notice our mistake until some time later. And so now we have a production database full of data, having two schemas "dbo" and "report" and using only migration history table.

Since recently our report migrations configuration class is implementing `DbMigrationsConfiguration<ReportContext>` and migrations are enabled. This does not bother me for deployment reasons, since I made sure that the initial migration id and hash are the same in production database and our code base.
The issue that is bothering me is that all of our development, qa and potentialy upcoming production environments are having a different database structure from our current production database structure.
So I would like to have the database generated by our code first migrations to be of same structure as our production database.